# How do you create objects using a for loop

Tags: javascript

I know this is probably really difficult, because I want something like Object1, Object2, etc.
This is what I think might work, but probably won't.

```
for(var x = 1; x<=10; x++){
    var Object + x = new Object();
};
```

What should I do instead. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use an array and on each iteration, create the object and push to that array.

Comment: This is called a `variable variable name`. Javascript does not support this functionality in the way you're trying to do it. It does support arrays with `string` indices. So you can do something more like `objects["Object + x"] = new Object();`

Comment: If working in the global scope : `window['Object' + x] = ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var objects = {};

for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
  objects[x] = {name: "value"};  //value can be a string like "value" or a var like value 
}
```